# My WHERE clause is not respecting the Condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using a join (Teachers Table and Linking (Bridge) Table) I am trying to retrieve TEACHERS Names

### MYSQL TABLES

1.) I have a Linking (Bridge) Table: I insert the relationships here

```
 Table Name "cl_st_tch"
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
 | classes_id  | students_id | teachers_id |  company_id   |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
 | 1           | 1           | 2           | 1             |
 | 1           | 2           | 4           | 1             |
 | 1           | 3           | 4           | 1             |
 | 1           | 4           | 4           | 1             |
 | 1           | 5           | 4           | 1             |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

2.) This is my Teachers Table : Simple table that stores Teachers First Names

```
 Table Name "teachers"
 +-------------+-------------+
 |id           | name        |
 +-------------+-------------+  
 | 1           | Sandra      |
 | 2           | Alex        |
 | 3           | Kinder      |
 | 4           | Michael     |
 +-------------+-------------+
```

### MYSQL QUERY

```
 SELECT 
 DISTINCT teachers.name, teachers.id, cl_st_tch.teachers_id 
 FROM teachers, cl_st_tch 
 WHERE teachers.id && cl_st_tch.teachers_id = 4
```

### "DESIRED" RESULTS

I would expect this to produce only 1 Name = Michael

### "UNDESIRED" RESULTS

Instead I am getting all the teachers names

Sandra
Alex
 
Kinder
 
Michael

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `WHERE teachers.id` means that if there is a `teachers.id` its true.  So every record is returned.

Comment: If you remove the `DISTINCT` keyword, you would see that the query is producing 16 rows, as a `CROSS JOIN` of four rows from `cl_st_tch (teachers_id=4)`, and four rows from `teachers (id<>0)`. Very likely you don't want a CROSS JOIN; likely you want to "match" rows `ON cl_st_tch.teachers_id = teachers.id`. (Also, ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, use the `JOIN` keyword instead, and move the join predicates to an `ON` clause.)

Comment: @paqogomez - Thanks for that clarification, I had not quite grasped that concept, however your explanation opened my eyes! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT teachers.name, teachers.id, cl_st_tch.teachers_id 
  FROM teachers
  INNER JOIN cl_st_tch
    ON teachers.id = cl_st_tch.teachers_id
  WHERE teachers.id = 4
```

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio, I implemented it and it worked like a BOSS!! Thanks for the education and the snippet!

Answer (score 1):

your query is not valid logically:

`WHERE teachers.id && cl_st_tch.teachers_id = 4`

change to:

`WHERE teachers.id = cl_st_tch.teachers_id and  teachers.id = 4`

Comment: Thanks @Jason, can I use && instead of and?

Comment: No use AND even && allowed!

Comment: So just to clarify, I should not use &&? Could you please elaborate just a little? I am still searching to understand this concept as much as I can? - Thanks again for your GURU help!

Comment: @DustinScottGarza `&&` is c# notation (and other languages).  You are in SQL, so its `AND`

Comment: @paqogomez - OOOOHHHHH....wow I had no IDEA, maybe it bled over from my limited knowledge of PHP as I have used it over there. Thanks again!